# Is there a faster way to compare multiple arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, optimization

I have a slow performance issue in comparing multiple arrays.

The algorithm that I've made is:

I'll be looping first the arrays by foreach

```php
foreach($branches as $index => $branch) {
    if (!$identical) {
        continue;
    }

    // Basically this $permissions will be fetching data from the database.
    $permissions = $this->get()
        ->where('user_id', $userId)
        ->where('branch_id', $userBranchId)
        ->sortBy('permission_id')
        ->pluck(['permission_id']);

    // if index = 0 then I'll initialize the temporary variable (ARRAY) $initial otherwise I'll compare two variable (ARRAY)
    if ($index === 0) {
        $initial = $permissions;
    } else {
        if ($initial != $permissions) {
            $identical = false;
        }
    }
}
```

So to compare multiple arrays, I use only this if condition and comparative symbol (==). But I'm thinking if

Comment: It depends on where the original array comes from.  It may be possible to do this processing at this point rather than having to loop through the array and check details there.  It's usually faster to reduce the number of database calls wherever possible for performance.

Comment: The optimal solution tho this code is to remove it, because it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Don't query database in loop, you can use array_column to export branches array to columns "userId" and "userBranchId"
finaly build query using "whereIn"

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @thaiha, you could reduce your queries to just one, and after make the comparison of the arrays. For example in Mysql you could do something like.

```
select * from `permissions` where (`user_id `, `branch_id `) in (('1', '2'), ('2', '4'));
```

then for comparing the arrays, you could do your loop, or use one of the php functions to compare arrays like array_diff is you are expecting all to match a specific set of permission. Or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping array. I suggest that use eager loading instead.

Branch model

```
public function permissions(){
 return $this->hasMany('App\Permission', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
}
```

and in your controller

```
Branch::with('permissions')->where($condition)->get();
```

Read document here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships